# How to display image metadata in openCV using c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, metadata, ubuntu-18.04

I want to select an image and show its metadata such as height, width, rgb values, format etc using opencv and c++. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you're trying to do. OpenCV does not read Exif metadata if that's what you're looking for, but the things you do explicitly mention in your question are obtainable *without* looking at the metadata.

Comment: I want to display as much as possible information about an image which includes opacity, number of pixels, filename, date of creation, filesize etc

Answer (score 2):

**Method I:**

If you want to learn your image's height,width and rgb values with code you can use:

```
Mat img = imread("image.jpg");
cout<< "Width:" << img.cols << "Height:" << img.rows << endl; // width and height
cout<< img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] << endl; // This code gives you the pixel value of a chosen coordinate.
//i and j are your coordinates. and 0 represents the first layer of BGR 
//values. You can change it with 1 or 2 to learn the other layer values
```

**Method II:**

If you want to learn your desired values using a screen, you can simply use 'imshow' function of opencv. From the screen you can findout the width and height. And you can also learn the rgb values of any point using your mouse. ( you can zoom any point with your mouse)

Comment: I need to display more metadata than just height and width. I am looking for information like file size, date of creation, opacity etc.